# PHP:Update in MySQL database table sets blank values in the columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am retrieving values from the database into the form for update, on the press of the submit button, the values should get updated.

Here's the code:

PostUpdate.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username=$_SESSION['uname'];


$cn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$course = $category = "";
$title = $descp = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["pid"]) && !empty($_POST["pid"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $pid = $_POST["pid"];


    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($course) && empty($category) && empty($title) && empty($descp)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET course=?, category=?, title=?, descp=? WHERE pid=?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $param_course, $param_category, $param_title, $param_descp, $param_pid);

            // Set parameters
            $param_course = $course;
            $param_category = $category;
            $param_title = $title;
            $param_descp = $descp;
            $param_pid = $pid;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: CAposts.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }


    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($cn);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["pid"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["pid"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $pid =  trim($_GET["pid"]);

        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE pid = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_pid);

            // Set parameters
            $param_pid = $pid;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $pid = $row['pid'];
                    $uname = $row['uname'];
                    $course = $row['course'];
                    $category = $row['category'];
                    $pdate = $row['pdate'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $descp = $row['descp'];

                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: CAposts.php");
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($cn);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: CAposts.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>


  <html>

  <head>
    <title>IMEDTalks-Post-
      <?php echo $title;?>
    </title>

    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>
      /* Make the image fully responsive */

      .carousel-inner img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30%;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h2 class="text-center">Update Post</h2>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">Please edit the input values and submit to update the post.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">


              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="col-form-label col-md-1 offset-3" for="course">Course:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <select name="course" class="form-control" required>
                      <option value="<?php echo $course;?>" selected>
                        <?php echo $course;?>
                      </option>
                      <option value="">Choose any:</option>
                      <option value="comp">Comp</option>
                      <option value="theo">Theory</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <label class="col-form-label col-md-1" for="category">Category:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                      <option value="<?php echo $category;?>" selected>
                        <?php echo $category;?>
                      </option>
                      <option value="">Choose any:</option>
                      <option value="plang">Programming Language</option>
                      <option value="web">Web Technologies</option>
                      <option value="maths">Mathematics and Statistics</option>

                      <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="title" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Title:
                        </label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title;?>" name="title" required>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="desc" class="col-form-label col-md-12">Description:
                        </label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="descp" rows="20" required><?php echo $descp;?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $pid;?>" />


              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-4 offset-4">
                  <a href="CAposts.php"><button type="button" name="cancel" 
                            class="btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Here, i am using pid which is being bought from the previous page where the data is listed in table format, and on the click of a button there, that data/post gets loaded into the form for editing and updating the same using the pid(primary key in my database table)
Iam using bootstrap 4.

Problem i am facing:

The update operation is performed without any errors using the pid, but the values of course, category, title, description gets set to blank in database table after this update operation.

I can't figure out whats going wrong here.

Comment: Do you mean to be checking for `!empty()` on those variables before the `UPDATE` query?

Comment: i don't know but making changes you suggested, now shows an error: 'undefined index pid on this line :  $pid = $row['pid'];

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($row);` right after `$row` is defined and investigate what that array looks like?

Comment: OK, so i tried what you suggested,
i added this: echo '<pre>', var_dump($row) ,'</pre>';

and i got this result:
array(4) {
  ["course"]=>
  string(3) "CA"
  ["category"]=>
  string(11) "Skills"
  ["title"]=>
  string(8) "try"
  ["descp"]=>
  string(13) "trytrytrytrytrytrytyrtry"
}
so, here clearly, pid is missing, but why so, i cant understand, as it has a int value in my database.

Comment: That is peculiar, especially since `pid` is the column used in your `WHERE` clause in the query. While this may not resolve the case of the missing column, what if you don't re-assign `$pid` from the `$row` array as it is already declared above. Still strange though

Comment: removing the line: $pid = $row['pid'];  removes the error, but the update operation doesn't works, on click of the submit button it redirects to the same page and with an empty form, and the database remains unaffected after this operation.
I know this i ats strange problem, and this error wasn't even there before, earlier the operation worked, but it just produced wrong output on the DB as the columns were set to blank.